# Windows Azure web.config changed

Tags: azure

Recently I had a problem with a service in Windows Azure, I've deploy the app to staging with a connection string to test DB, before I swap to production, i've change the connection string to production DB, that was on saturday, but today at my production environment the connections strings were to test DB.

Is there an schedule to recycle the instances in windows Azure?
If there is, Where did azure took the package to create the new instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you change the connection string before the swap? did you remove into the azure instances? or redeploy the solution with a new web.config in cspkg file?

Answer (score 0):

Azure can recycle your cloud service (Web and Worker) roles at any time and you don't have any control on that.  When you deploy your service, it is stored in Azure storage and instances are created from that.  Once deployed, you can't change the Web.config file because if redeployed, the new instance will use the original settings stored in your deployment package.  It is best practice to store connection strings in the service configuration file instead of the Web.config file since you can change it at runtime.

Check this SO Q/A for the how to: [Set the application ConnectionString in the Service Configuration instead of web.config in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979562/set-the-application-connectionstring-in-the-service-configuration-instead-of-web)